# BigQuery select alias using regex_extract_all in standard mode

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm unable to reference a `SELECT` alias in BigQuery (standard mode).

Trying to do this query:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(text,
    r"(<div \w+>)") AS matches
FROM
  regex.test
WHERE
  matches IS NOT NULL
```

Here are steps to reproduce.

```
bq mk regex
bq mk -t regex.test id:integer,text:string
echo '{"id":1, "text":"<div a>"}' | bq insert regex.test
echo '{"id":2, "text":"<div b>"}' | bq insert regex.test
echo '{"id":3, "text":"<div>"}' | bq insert regex.test

bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "select REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(text, r\"(<div \w+>)\") AS matches FROM regex.test WHERE id IS NOT NULL"

+--------------+
|   matches    |
+--------------+
| [u'<div b>'] |
| []           |
| [u'<div a>'] |
+--------------+
```

When I try to reference the `matches` alias, I see an error:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "select REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(text, r\"(<div \w+>)\") AS matches FROM regex.test WHERE matches IS NOT NULL"
Error in query string: Error processing job 'myname': Unrecognized name:
matches
```

I am unable to reference the alias `matches`, and am unable to filter those results `WHERE matches IS NOT NULL`.

Does anyone know what I'm doing incorrectly here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even in BQ, you can't use a column alias in the `where` clause.  Just use a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(text, r"(<div \w+>)") AS matches
      FROM regex.test
     ) t
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(matches) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I just added the part for `ARRAY_LENGTH` (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#array_length)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [SELECT list aliases visibility](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/query-syntax#explicit-alias-visibility)

The reason why comparing with NULL does't work for `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL` is because 
it returns array so checking with length is the way.  Comparing with NULL still will work for `REGEXP_EXTRACT`

In addition, ideally you should be able use REGEX_MATCH to filter out records w/o matches, but looks like there is an issue with this function in standard mode

Comment: Thanks! I found that `REGEXP_CONTAINS` will work instead of `REGEX_MATCH` in standard SQL mode

Comment: Good finding. Thank you for sharing!